Set DNS destination of subdomains and additional wildcard
This is how DNS is configured for domain.com
Host | Type | MX | Destination
*    | A    |    | 123.456.789.0
@    | A    |    | 123.456.789.0

That means every request to domain.com or sub.domain.com will be send to 123.456.789.0.
Now I need to configure specific two subdomain (registry.domain.com and ci.domain.com), which should have a different destination IP (e.g. 123.987.654.0), while all other subdomain should have still the destination 123.456.789.0
Is this possible and how do I have to do it?

Many DNS server implementations will only return the wildcard record when no other specific records exists, so quite likely you can simply add the A , AAAA and/or CNAME or other records for registry.example.com and ci.example.com and they should work as expected
